# How to specify name and folder when i save stl?

Tags: python, vtk

I have a vtkpolydata and i know how to save it like stl:

```
    stlWriter = vtk.vtkSTLWriter()
    stlWriter.SetFileName("gomaMI.stl")
    stlWriter.SetInputConnection(self.modeloMI.GetOutputPort())
    stlWriter.Write()
```

The problem is that i dont want to save it by code I want to specify the folder and name in a new window, like all programs. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

Tk().withdraw() 
filename = asksaveasfilename()
print(filename)
```

As per your code if you `SetFileName` to whatever is returned by `filename` assuming it isn't an empty string this will work.

PyQt5 is nicer to look at but requires more lines of code `easygui` would also offer a solution.